# VBA: I want to input a model number on one sheet and have it output the IMEI, both are databased in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Exactly like the title says, on one sheet I want to be able to input as many model numbers as I want and have it output the IMEI number. The other sheet has an archive of all of the model numbers and their IMEI numbers (as well as the serial number but I don't care about that).

So input a model number on sheet2 and have excel find in sheet1 the matching model number, find the correlating IMEI, copy the IMEI, and paste it in sheet2 next to where the model number was input.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH`? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

sheet 2 column A starting at row 2 list of model number

sheet 1 column A starting at row 2 list of model number

sheet 1 column B starting at row 2 list of imei number

```
Sub FindAndCopy()
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, imeinum As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    lastRow = sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(sht2.Range("A" & i).Value, sht1.Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
                imeinum = Application.Match(sht2.Range("A" & i).Value, sht1.Range("A:A"), 0)
                sht2.Range("B" & i).Value = sht1.Range("B" & imeinum).Value
            Else
                sht2.Range("B" & i).Value = "NO MATCH"
            End If
    Next i
End Sub
```